# Electron: Using mainWindow.webContents.send when mainWindow loads

Tags: javascript, electron

When a user changes the theme, I use `mainWindow.webContents.send` to change a class in the DOM. I also save it in the store, under the key `theme`.

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('theme:change', theme);
store.set('theme', theme);
```

Then in `renderer.js`:

```
ipcRenderer.on('theme:change', (event, theme) => {
  document.querySelector('body').className = `${theme}`;
});
```

This successfully changes the theme and saves it in the store. However, now I want that theme to load up when starting the application rather than going back to the default. To do this, in `app.on('ready')` I am doing this:

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('theme:change', store.get('theme'));
```

However, nothing is happening. It's like it isn't being sent. Where am I going wrong? Essentially what needs to be done is for the class in `body` to be changed when the application loads to the one in the store.

Comment: Is that line of code (`send(...)`) getting hit, and if so, is `store.get` set to what you want? If it is, then presumably the handler in the renderer isn't firing. We might need some more context to help. If you're sending the message right when the app `ready` event fires, it may be too early - maybe the renderer hasn't added the handler yet... depends on your code. Do you have a MVCE?

Comment: It does not seem to be getting hit. No matter what value I use, like `mainWindow.webContents.send('testing')`, it doesn't fire. If I `console.log(store.get('theme'))` it prints it accurately.

Comment: Actually, I found out something. If I put a small delay, it works. The DOM must not be ready. But wrapping it in `mainWindow.on('dom-ready')` doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. I had to put:

```
mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('theme:change', store.get('theme'));
})
```

I was trying `mainWindow.on('dom-ready')` which is why it wasn't working.